# How can Sentry.io be integrated into a Node-RED?

Tags: node-red, sentry

It seems that support does not directly exist for linking Node-RED with Sentry.io. In order to realize this goal, AFAIK, the steps that need to be taken include:

1. Create a custom node to be published in the Node-RED library
2. Create a [custom logger](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/logging) to intercept log messages
3. **Import and integrate the sentry browser client**
4. Define the node properties (appearance, credential storage)
5. Write unit tests

My primary concern is how to integrate the sentry.io client. Other examples ([logging to MySQL](https://flows.nodered.org/flow/59fe2502dd82ae9b8a55b949a48e3d89)) seem very hacky and do not show importing external JavaScript libraries. Can this also be realized as a [custom node](https://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sentry/node because this is our node SDK.

Sending something to Sentry is very simple, to get started, here are our docs: https://docs.sentry.io/error-reporting/quickstart/?platform=node

I am not really familiar with our Node-RED works, but it's probably something similar to:

```
module.exports = function(RED) {
    function SentryNode(config) {
        RED.nodes.createNode(this, config);
        var node = this;
        Sentry.init({dsn: 'YOUR DSN'});
        node.on('input', function(msg) {
            Sentry.captureMessage(msg.payload);
            node.send(msg);
        });
    }
    RED.nodes.registerType("Sentry", SentryNode);
}
```